# Which element added in magento admin backup?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, backup

I want to know the exact use of below backup setting.

1. System backup -> is system configuration settings are stored and where stored?
2. Database and Media backup -> is media files are including on this backup?
3. Database backup -> this is for whole database backup?

Your inputs is really appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Any type of backup you select, saved data to var\backups\ folder

System backup - store file structure including images is saved
Database and Media Backup - media folder with images and database backup are saved
Database backup - store database is backed up